# Power Mta Won't start

Tags: linux, email, centos6.2

I rebooted my linux server. Now PMTA won't start

here is the output using --debug

```
Resources allow for at most 0 pipe delivery thread(s)

Open file limit (ulimit -H -n) too low (4086), need at least 7798

SMTP Listener at 0.0.0.0:26 stopped

Stopping remaining threads...

Startup error: Insufficient process resources
```

Please help

Comment: What's in your logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, see this line:

> Open file limit (ulimit -H -n) too low (4086), need at least 7798

It seems you set your open file limit too low, change it to higher than `7798`, then restart.

**Edited**

You can change it by steps:

Edit sysctl.conf file:

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add this line:

```
fs.file-max = 9999
```

Then run command to load config:

```
sysctl -p
```

Check:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

Comment: How do I change that?